# Kali won't boot without USB flash drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

I have installed Linux Kali on one of partitions of my hard drive alongside Windows 10 from USB Flash Drive (I had a bootable live version with HDD install option) and it's not booting when the flash drive from which I installed it is not inserted. When I turn on computer, GRUB appears, I choose Kali and it keeps showing me this

[image]

I really don't know what can cause this. I've tried to set kali install partition as primary and flag it to boot but it didn't work. At first I have thought that maybe this is caused by Windows which blocks hard drive after shutdown (I needed to boot to Windows and then reboot to access drives when I was using live version) but if so, then why it boots after inserting flash drive? Furthermore when it boots properly (with flashdrive) I can remove it and it works fine.

Comment: I think you may have installed the boot partition for your Kali onto your USB instead of your hard drive. I recommend you use something like gparted on another computer to inspect the partitions of your USB. If this is the case, then you will need to remove the Kali partitions on you computer, put a clean USB and be careful when setting up where your partitions go during the install stage.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks a lot. Sorry for late response but I haven't got time to reinstall it again.
During partitioning process, Kali made a boot partition on the pendrive and I missed it.

Comment: Glad to help!... Now if only you could mark comments as answers ;)

Comment: idk how to do it and if it's even possible, afaik not. Just post your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation process, the Kali Linux installer (Debian re-skinned) is prone to placing the boot partition onto the USB. To remedy this you will need to reformat the USB, and ensure that during the installation process the boot partition is placed onto the correct hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the USB again using rufus. it need to download some extra files and choose the default option when it shows you options of booting.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so, and provide some additional information about the extra files required.

Comment: the problem i think is, the way it was booted...there is a standard mode and dd mode(mostly for linux) and i think rufus does this thoroughly so you dont encounter problems like this... and the files rufus automatically downloads is needed to make a linux os bootable for a flash drive